# why does it seem that sleep doesn't work in goroutine

Tags: time, go, sleep, goroutine

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    c := make(chan struct{})
    count := 1
    go func() {
        for {
            fmt.Println("foo", count)
            count++
            time.Sleep(2)
        }
        c <- struct{}{}
    }()
    fmt.Println("Hello World!")
    <-c
}
```

This is my code , and I found it didn't sleep 2 every loop, and printed quickly. What's the reason of it? What I searched is that sleep will make goroutine give up control of cpu and when it get the control again will it check itself is sleeping?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[time.Sleep](http://golang.org/pkg/time/#Sleep) takes its [Duration](http://golang.org/pkg/time/#Duration) in nanoseconds, so to delay 2 seconds it should be;

```
time.Sleep(2000000000)
```

or, as @Ainar-G points out in the comments, the more readable;

```
time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
```

Comment: Or rather ``time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)``.