# Why won't time.Sleep work in time.Tick?, instead waits 10 seconds

Tags: go

i have the code:

```golang
    n := time.Now()
    i := 0
    for range time.Tick(5 * time.Second) {
        fmt.Printf("start %d %s \n ", i, time.Since(n))
        time.Sleep(10)
        fmt.Printf("end %d %s \n", i, time.Since(n))
        i++
    }
```

output:

```bash
start 0 5.001125s 
 end 0 5.001386916s 
start 1 10.001112041s 
 end 1 10.001232416s 
start 2 15.001064s 
 end 2 15.001094958s
```

Trigger every 5 seconds, program execution takes 10 seconds, I found that the sleep method does not take effect, every 5 seconds will automatically print `end`, no wait 10 seconds.

question:

1. What is the reason for this?
2. I need to wait until the execution of the program in each loop is complete before I start recalculating the 5 seconds. What do I do?

Comment: `time.Sleep` [pauses the current goroutine](https://pkg.go.dev/time#Sleep) while other goroutines/threads/etc still run concurrently; it doesn't suspend entire program execution.

Comment: Typo?  `time.Sleep(10 * time.Second)`. See related question https://stackoverflow.com/q/24889431/20145018

Answer (score 1):

> What is the reason for this?

`time.Sleep` takes a parameter of type [time.Duration](https://pkg.go.dev/time#Duration) which under the covers is an `int64` representing nanoseconds.

As a result, this sleeps for 10 nanoseconds:

```
time.Sleep(10)
```

To sleep for 10 seconds, use one of the predefined `const`s:

```
time.Sleep(10*time.Second)
```

---

> I need to wait until the execution of the program in each loop is complete before I start recalculating the 5 seconds

If you want to wait at least `5s` *between* each loop iteration - then don't use a `Ticker`. A ticker will loop on a regular interval. Some examples:

- if a loop task takes 2s, then the next loop iteration will begin in 3s (5 minus 2)
- if the task takes 8s (missing a tick), then there will be zero wait between iterations;
- if the task takes 12s (missing 2 ticks) - again there will be zero wait

So if you want to ensure a consistent pause between iterations, put a sleep at the end of the loop.